# MotionEye OS: How to run additional services?

Tags: motion

is it possible to run additional services with MotionEye OS ?
Trying to make a baby monitor with sound monitoring and triggering, OPenVPN, DDNS server, Blynk server, DHT22 sensor,...
I already done it with MotionEye on Stretch but the video feed is sooooo slowww...

THank you guys

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: By run additional services do you mean install things like openvpn??? If so, no you can't. Motioneyeos is a read-only system so you can't alter it significantly beyond the settings available to you in the UI. When you say you've done it already with motion eye on stretch what exactly do you mean. If it's going slow that sounds like a configuration issue or your trying to do too much on one pi.

Comment: The important functionnality I need from MotionEye is fast network camera. It is available from the MotionEye OS but not from the MotionEye application install from what I've seen.